# Where and how can I install twitter's Python API?

Tags: api, twitter

I went to twitter's API, it redirected me to google code, and the website wasn't there. Any alternative twitter APIs, plus tutorials? thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Tweepy: http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/

You can get to a [tutorial wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/wiki/GettingStarted) for it at the same Google Code link.

To install it with easy_install, just run `easy_install tweepy`

To install it with git:

```
git clone git://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python setup.py install
```

To install it from source, download the source from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweepy then run something like:

```
tar xzvf tweepy-1.7.1.tar.gz
cd tweepy-1.7.1
python setup.py install
```

Comment: its great, but I cannot import it! how do i do that?

Comment: I added install instructions. After you've installed it, `import tweety` should just work.

Comment: Thanks :) does this work for 3rd party editors like textmate aswell?

Comment: Not sure, I don't have a lot of experience using TextMate with Python... sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [Python-Twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) for the past couple of months.
It makes it extremely easy to pull data from the Twitter API as well as post Tweets.

You can install via pip:

```
pip install python-twitter
```

or by cloning from git => https://github.com/bear/python-twitter.git
then installing the dependencies (which can be done via pip)
follow the instructions in README.rt

```
python setup.py build
```

then

```
python setup.py install
```

After you've installed the library, I'd recommend setting up a simple authentication file (eg. twitterAuth.py) like this one:

```
# twitterAuth.py

import twitter

"""This script is meant to connect to the Twitter API via the tokens below"""

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='yourConsumerKeyGoesHere',
    consumer_secret='yourConsumerSecretGoesHere',
    access_token_key='your-AccessTokenGoesHere',
    access_token_secret='yourTokenSecretGoesHere')
```

Then you can simply import this from any scripts that need to acccess the Twitter API.  Here's a simple example that posts a Tweet:

```
from twitter import * 
import twitterAuth

api = twitterAuth.api

status = api.PostUpdate('testing twitter-python')
print status.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Twitter maintains an [ongoing list of libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries) a developer can use in many different languages, including Python. Honestly, the easiest method is just using the Python `requests` library and performing a simple HTTP request to one of the many [REST endpoints](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public).

Here is an example I wrote to search the Twitter tweets REST endpoint:

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1 # For authentication

_consumer_key = <api_key>
_consumer_secret = <api_secret>
_key = <token>
_secret = <token_secret>

_auth = OAuth1(_consumer_key, _consumer_secret, _key, _secret)

def search(search_terms):
    # Twitter search URL:
    url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json'
    payload = {
        'q': search_terms,  # May be @user_search or #hash_search also
        'lang': 'en',  # Based on ISO 639-1 two-letter code
        'result_type': 'mixed',
        'count': '100',  # Number of tweets to return per page, up to a max of 100
        'until': Get_Time()['today']
    }
    search_results = requests.get(url, auth=_auth, params=payload)
    print search_results.json() # Gets the raw results in json format
```

To create api and token keys and secrets, you need to create an app here at [apps.twitter.com](https://apps.twitter.com/). Twitter has a very user friendly REST api and documentation, so I believe it will be easy to understand once you do a few HTTP requests and receive appropriate responses.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) is a very user friendly twitter API.

Comment: is this not the same as the above answer?