# ImportError: No module named tweepy - In python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tweepy

i am trying to do a Sentiment analysis using AWS as explained in the following section
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/emr/getting-started-emr-sentiment-tutorial.html

Everything went fine until I encountered the following error
[ec2-user@ip-10-65-140-113 sentiment]$ ls
enter code herecollector.py  twaiter.py  twaiter.pyc  twitterparams.py

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-65-140-113 sentiment]$ **collector.py kindle**
-bash: collector.py: command not found
[ec2-user@ip-10-65-140-113 sentiment]$ python collector.py kindle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "collector.py", line 6, in <module>
    from twaiter import TWaiter
  File "/home/ec2-user/sentiment/twaiter.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tweepy import StreamListener
**ImportError: No module named tweepy**
```

Any help as to why this could be. twaiter.py has the following content. I opened the twaiter.py to see line no 5 and is here

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-65-140-113 sentiment]$ vi twaiter.py


 1 # based on http://badhessian.org/2012/10/collecting-real-time-twitter-data-w    ith-the-streaming-api/
  2 # with modifications by http://github.com/marciw
  3 # requires Tweepy https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
  4
  5 from tweepy import StreamListener
  6 import json, time, sys
  7
  8 class TWaiter(StreamListener):
  9
 10     # see Tweepy for more info
 11
 12     def __init__(self, api = None, label = 'default_collection'):
 13         self.api = api or API()
 14         self.counter = 0
 15         self.label = label
 16         self.output  = open(label + '.' + time.strftime('%b%d-%H%M') + '.txt    ', 'w')
 17         self.deleted  = open('deleted_tweets.txt', 'a')
 18
 19     def on_data(self, data):
 20         # The presence of 'in_reply_to_status' indicates a "normal" tweet.
@
```

Comment: The error says it all - the `tweepy` module cannot be imported. Are you sure it is installed?

Answer (score 1):

The message "ImportError: No module named tweepy" clearly shows that the ec2 machine does not have tweepy library installed. So while running the current python script, it is not able to locate it and therefore giving import error.

There are several ways to install tweepy. One simple way in Linux machine is
    **sudo pip install tweepy**

Other ways are:

http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/

You can get to a tutorial wiki page for it at the same Google Code link.

To install it with easy_install, just run easy_install tweepy

To install it with git:

git clone git://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python setup.py install
To install it from source, download the source from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweepy then run something like:

tar xzvf tweepy-1.7.1.tar.gz
cd tweepy-1.7.1
python setup.py install

Please refer [Where and how can I install twitter's Python API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957495/where-and-how-can-i-install-twitters-python-api) for further details.

Also, if further error comes refer [ImportError: No module named tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451316/importerror-no-module-named-tweepy)